# Is it possible to resize objects in pygame based on screen_with and screen height

Tags: pygame

```py
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
import random

class Alien(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single alien in the fleet"""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize the alien and set its starting position."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        # load the alien image and set its rect attribute.
        image_number = random.randint(1, 4)

        if image_number == 1:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.png').convert_alpha()
            infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (infoObject.current_w / 10,infoObject.current_h / 10))
        if image_number == 2:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien 2.png').convert_alpha()
            infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (infoObject.current_w / 10,infoObject.current_h / 10))
        if image_number == 3:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien 3.png').convert_alpha()
            infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (infoObject.current_w / 10,infoObject.current_h / 10))
        if image_number == 4:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien 4.png').convert_alpha()
            infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (infoObject.current_w / 10,infoObject.current_h / 10))
        if image_number == 5:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.png').convert_alpha()
            infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (infoObject.current_w / 10,infoObject.current_h / 10))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

With this code I randomize my aliens but i often switch between displays and this causes the amount of aliens to differ from screen to screen. So i was wondering if it is possible to change the size of the aliens based on the screen size. Currently im getting the error "integer argument expected, got float"

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.transform.scale` takes a `size` parameter, which is `(width, height)`. This width and height must be integers.

So in your case, instead of:

`self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (infoObject.current_w / 10,infoObject.current_h / 10))`

You could do: (cast the results into integers)

`self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int(infoObject.current_w / 10), int(infoObject.current_h / 10)))`

However, there is a simpler way. Python has integer division built in, which achieves the same result are dividing then casting. This type of division uses two "/" characters and always outputs integers.

`self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (infoObject.current_w // 10), infoObject.current_h // 10))`

From a program design perspective, it's a bit gnarly to create a display Info object in every if statement, and recalculate the size every time. There's also a lot of other general repetition.

Here's my attempt at a cleaner section:

```
        # load the alien image and set its rect attribute.
        image_number = random.randint(1, 4)

        self.image = pygame.image.load(f"images/alien {image_number}.png") # this does require you to rename "alien.png" to "alien 1.png"
        w, h = screen.get_size() # you already have the screen surface, you can get size that way
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (w//10, h//10))
```

Also, it doesn't affect you at all now, but I just so happened to have added float support to `pygame.transform.scale` and `pygame.transform.smoothscale` the other day, in https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2581. So in the future, the integer division part may be unnecessary.